# Need a scrollbar to a usercontrol in window form when the form is resized

Tags: winforms

I am using a UserControl say "SearchItem" in which  I am having a textbox and a listbox and a button.On click of button the listbox is populated.The Usercontrol is kept in a panel.My Question is when I am minimizing the window the usercontrol is not getting set to the size like the other controls are getting the scrollbars.I need to set the scroll bar for the usercontrol too.Please let me know if any body worked on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

OK, let see. The user control is inside of a panel on the main forms, Correct?

If the user control is set to **DOCK = NONE**, and the panel is set to **ANCHOR TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT** and the panel has **AUTOSCROLL = TRUE**, it should create the scroll bars on the panel when the form is resized.

Is this the correct behaviour you require?